# SQLAlchemy ORM: Using func in update

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use `func` in an update statement, but I'm getting an InvalidRequest error (stacktrace below). Here's the code:

```
session.query(C).filter(
    z == True,
).update({
    C.x: func.sqrt((C.y1 + C.y2) * 0.675)
})
```

And here's the stacktrace:

```
  File "/var/xxx/vagrant-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3288, in update
    update_op.exec_()
  File "/var/xxx/vagrant-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1167, in exec_
    self._do_pre_synchronize()
  File "/var/xxx/vagrant-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1236, in _do_pre_synchronize
    "Could not evaluate current criteria in Python. "
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not evaluate current criteria in Python. Specify 'fetch' or False for the synchronize_session parameter.
```

I tried with both `func.sqrt` and `func.round` but they both give the error above. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify `synchronize_session` [strategy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=query.update#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update.params.synchronize_session) - `False`,`'fetch'` or implement `evaluate`. Just add it as a parameter, for example

```
session.query(C).filter(
    z == True,
).update({
    C.x: func.sqrt((C.y1 + C.y2) * 0.675)
}, synchronize_session='fetch')
```